# RTL in DOCX4J with Word 2019 using Java

Tags: java, ms-word, xhtml, right-to-left, docx4j

I'm trying to generate text (Arabic + English) sent from **xhtml webpage** to a **.docx file** (2019 version), using **docx4j library**. But it seems that the library does not support RTL direction on Word 2019.

However, it works well using Word 2013.

Screenshots:

Word2013-Generated

[image: 1]

Word2019-Generated

[image: 2]

Comment: Attach a sample of the relevant OpenXML, as editable text please.

Comment: Hello  JasonPlutex,
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_mL0c21_n0LAR1e10iqmJIDKDxQ4cQyh?usp=sharing
The link above contains the .docx files

Comment: The template in which the textbox had been replaced is also attached to the link.

Answer (score 0):

Its not immediately obvious how you are creating your generated2013.docx and generated2019.docx, however the difference between your 2013 docx (which I understand looks as you expect) and the 2019 one is the presence of the **rtl** rPr.

Relevant part of your 2013 docx:

```
          <w:p>
              <w:pPr>
                <w:bidi/>
              </w:pPr>
              <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                  <w:rFonts w:cs="Calibri"/>
                  <w:rtl/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>يجب</w:t>
              </w:r>
              <w:r>
                <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
              </w:r>
              <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                  <w:rFonts w:cs="Calibri"/>
                  <w:rtl/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>إدخال</w:t>
              </w:r>
```

compared to your 2019 docx:

```
            <w:p>
              <w:pPr>
                <w:bidi/>
              </w:pPr>
              <w:r>
                <w:t>يجب</w:t>
              </w:r>
              <w:r>
                <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
              </w:r>
              <w:r>
                <w:t>إدخال</w:t>
              </w:r>
```

Comment: Thank alot !! I solved the problem by formatting the string..String[] lines = s.split("\n");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  sb.append("\u202B");   // right-to-left embedding 
  sb.append(lines[i]);
  sb.append("\u202C\n"); // pop directional formatting
}                  
s = sb.toString();